# Android - Sqlite database method undefined for type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: android

i want to call inserttable method from RechargeActivity.java file, where the definition lies in another TryUIOpenHelper.java , where my databse and tables are created. I wish to know better way to to this.. Please help

```
     public class RechargeActivity extends Activity   {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.rechtable);

     RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rtt1); 
     RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rtt2); 
     final TextView amount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.amount1);
     final TextView talktime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.talktime1);
     final TextView validity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.validity1);  
     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);

     final TryUIOpenHelper helper=new TryUIOpenHelper(this);
     final SQLiteDatabase dbDatabase=helper.getWritableDatabase();
     final Date date = new Date(); 
     Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
     int  year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     int  month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);      // 0 to 11
     int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 

     String val=""+(day)+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+(year+1)+"";
         validity.setText(val);

     try{
     rb1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener ()
     {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   
          //Error here: The method inserttable(SQLiteDatabase) is undefined       for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
    inserttable(dbDatabase);

           } 
          });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }   

    rb2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener ()
     {
    public void onClick(View v)
      { 

      } } );

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    final Intent intent = 
    new Intent(RechargeActivity.this,       NumForRecharge.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     //db.close();

      }         
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

call it on your `TryUIOpenHelper` object

```
helper.inserttable(dbDatabase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 rb1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener ()
     {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   

     TryUIOpenHelper openHelper=new TryUIOpenHelper();
    openHelper.inserttable(dbDatabase);

           } 
          });
```

Change your onClickListener Like this.

**Reason:** When you try to use a method which lies in some other Class, you need to create a Object for that class and only then you can call a method from that class(Assuming it is public method). If it is a private method then you will not be able to access it.

Similarly if that method is a static one, you need not create a object for that class. Simply `ClassName.MethodName();` will do.